# i want to remove <![CDATA[ ]]> in xml?

Tags: php, xml

in xml file,i am displaying mysql data using php ..In that,i used `<![CDATA[ data  ]]>` 
in that some content is coming .some empty tags are there like this `"<![CDATA[   ]]>";`
i want to remove that all how?

can you please tell me that one.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you just wish to remove the empty ones, you may use a regular expression replace. See this code for an example.

```
$xml = "<tags>
  <tag><![CDATA[here is content]]></tag>
  <tag><![CDATA[     ]]></tag>
</tags>";
$cleanedXml = preg_replace('/<!\[CDATA\[\s*\]\]>/ims', '', $xml);
```

The output then would be:

```
<tags>
  <tag><![CDATA[here is content]]></tag>
  <tag></tag>
</tags>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it's not deleting ...see that img .my output like that only

Comment: your regular exp deleting sing space CDATA tags.But there is multiple spaces are there.please give regular expression for that..@dieBeiden